# Block youtube music videos from Fortinet

Tags: fortinet

Is it possible to block just youtube video music from Fortinet? I need my users can watch videos like tutorials from youtube but not music or another kind of entertaiment.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In a word: no. YouTube provides no mechanisms to allow a network device like a firewall to differentiate between content types.
The only method I'm aware of that sort of works is to use a proxy to set a volume quota on YouTube or other streaming media sites in general, high enough so that the odd business use is possible, but streaming music videos all day is not.